Why does the decomposition of hydrogen peroxide with KI have lower activation energies than the uncatalyzed decomposition?
I cannot wrap my head around why this reaction mechanism:

has smaller activation energies than

My interpretation of the former is that one of the oxygen atoms removes itself from the hydrogen peroxide and binds with the iodide ion to form hypoiodite and water. The oxygen atom then breaks off from the hypoiodite again and binds with a newly detached oxygen atom from a different hydrogen peroxide molecule, forming oxygen gas, water, and iodide.
My interpretation of the latter is very similar, where two hydrogen peroxide molecules have two oxygen atoms each remove themselves from it. The oxygen atoms bind to form oxygen gas and water.
Is this correct? If so, why would the catalyzed reaction be energetically favorable? In this reaction, two hydrogen peroxide molecules both have an oxygen atom detach itself like in the uncatalyzed reaction, but one of the oxygen atoms also needs to bind and unbind to an iodide ion. Would this not make for a more challenging reaction mechanism?
Is the lowered activation energy perhaps due to the non-simultaneity of the oxygen detachment from the hydrogen peroxide? In the uncatalyzed reaction, two hydrogen peroxide molecules must detach their oxygen atoms at the same time, meaning that these molecules must collide with twice the energy needed for one detachment, making for a higher activation energy. Meanwhile in the catalyzed reaction, one oxygen atom is detached at a time since the molecule first collides with an iodide ion, halving the activation energy for the first transition state.
Please correct my interpretation.


The ion $\ce{IO-}$ is not an oxygen iodide. It is the ion hypoiodite. 2) Maybe the iodide ion $\ce{I-}$ and $\ce{H2O2}$ forms a sort of intermediate state $\ce{H2O2I-}$ which requires a smaller activation energy to be formed than the energy needed to loose one oxygen atom from $\ce{H2O2}$.


Catalysis is not easy to predict, in many cases. Think in terms of a Feynman diagram for a nuclear particle - there are many possible paths from initial state (2 H2O2) to final (H2O + O2). Adding iodine creates other possible paths, and some may require less energy to "get over the hump" of activation energy than the straight path.
